# getRange takes only one value - Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to copy the range a21:ay21 to a new sheet but the formula only copies the first value (a21).

I'm stuck with it. Thanks!

```
function submitToDataBase() {
  var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formSS    = ss.getSheetByName("form"); //Form Sheet
  
  var datasheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data_Base"); //Data Sheet
  
  //Input Values
  var values = [[formSS.getRange("form!a21:ay21").getValues()]];
         
  datasheet.getRange(datasheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 50).setValues(values);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that in your script, `values` is a 4-dimensional array. And, `a21:ay21` has 51 columns. If you want to use `getValues` and `setValues`, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var values = [[formSS.getRange("form!a21:ay21").getValues()]];
       
datasheet.getRange(datasheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 50).setValues(values);
```

#### To:

```
var values = formSS.getRange("form!a21:ay21").getValues(); // formSS.getRange("a21:ay21").getValues();
datasheet.getRange(datasheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, 51).setValues(values);
```

- As another method, I think that in your situation, you can use `appendRow` as follows.

  ```
    var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var formSS    = ss.getSheetByName("form"); //Form Sheet
    var datasheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data_Base"); //Data Sheet
    var values = formSS.getRange("form!a21:ay21").getValues(); // formSS.getRange("a21:ay21").getValues();
    datasheet.appendRow(values[0]);
  ```
- As another method, I think that in your situation, you can use `copyTo` of Class Range as follows.

  ```
    var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var formSS    = ss.getSheetByName("form"); //Form Sheet
    var datasheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data_Base"); //Data Sheet
    formSS.getRange("a21:ay21").copyTo(datasheet.getRange(datasheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1), { contentsOnly: true });
  ```

#### References:

- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)
- [appendRow(rowContents)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendRow(Object))
- [copyTo(destination, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination,-options)

Answer (score -1):

Is this a named range?

```
var values = [[formSS.getRange("form!a21:ay21").getValues()]];
```

I would try deleting form from "form!a21:ay21", or simply using the named range writing the following in one of two ways

```
var values = [[formSS.getRange("form").getValues()]];

var values = [[formSS.getRange("!a21:ay21").getValues()]];
```